# packages installation issues with R 4.1.0

Tags: r

> Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : cannot open the connection
> In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : cannot open compressed file 'shiny/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Here are the error messages that I am receiving from R 4.1.0 when installing some packages (tidyverse, shiny). I am using R console with windows system. Thank you

Comment: would downgrading to 4.0.5 solve the problem? I'm also having some issues with version 4.1.0

Comment: Greetings!
Yeah, I have version 4.0.3 and this is working perfectly. With software, it is better to update constantly to do not miss new features. Thank you so much.